# How can I draw this figure using latex?

Tags: diagrams, tikz-arrows, draw, tikz-graphdrawing, physics

[image: Oscillator amortized by solid friction]

How can I draw this figure using LaTex ?

Comment: It's better if you have done some trials and decide what package you intend to use.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Quite a few diagrams of this type exist already on this site, but maybe not yet with `patterns.meta`, which gives us easier control over the patterns. (One could also employ the `angles` library but this may be a bit of an overkill for one arc.)

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing,patterns.meta} 
\pgfdeclarepattern{
name=shatch, parameters={\hatchsize,\hatchangle,\hatchlinewidth}, 
bottom left={\pgfpoint{-.1pt}{-.1pt}},
top right={\pgfpoint{\hatchsize+.1pt}{\hatchsize+.1pt}}, tile size={\pgfpoint{\hatchsize}{\hatchsize}},
tile transformation={\pgftransformrotate{\hatchangle}}, code={
\pgfsetlinewidth{\hatchlinewidth} 
\pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{-.1pt}{\hatchsize/2}} 
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\hatchsize+.1pt}{\hatchsize/2}} 
\pgfusepath{stroke}
} }
\tikzset{
hatch size/.store in=\hatchsize,
hatch angle/.store in=\hatchangle,
hatch line width/.store in=\hatchlinewidth, 
hatch size=5pt,
hatch angle=0pt,
hatch line width=.5pt,
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[declare function={beta=30;},>=stealth,semithick]
 \begin{scope}[rotate=-beta]
  \path[pattern=shatch] (0,0) rectangle (-0.4,1.2); 
  \draw[<->] (0,2) node[right] {$y$} |- (6,0) node[right]{$x$}
   coordinate[pos=0.95](x);
  \draw[decorate,decoration={zigzag,segment length=4mm,amplitude=2mm}]
   (0,0.2) -- (4,0.2) node[midway,above=2ex]{$(k,\ell)$};
  \draw[fill=cyan] (3.8,0) rectangle ++ (0.6,0.4); 
  \path (4.1,0.5) node[above right] {$M(m)$};
 \end{scope}
 \draw (x) -- ++ (-5,0);
 \draw (x) + (-2,0) arc[start angle=180,end angle=180-beta,radius=2]
  node[midway,left] {$\beta$};
 \draw[<-] (3,2) -- ++ (0,1); 
 \draw[->] (3.1,2.6) -- ++ (0.5,0) node[midway,below] {$g$}; 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1: my humble opinion. The arrows over g is very long.

Comment: @Sebastiano This is just a hint at the gravity of our current situation.